# Referencing variables in racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket

I'm trying to write a simple procedure for finding the n:th prime but I don't think I understand how to reference variables correctly in racket.

What I want is for the inner procedure **sieve-iter** to add primes to the list *primlst* which is in the namespace of **sieve** but I get an infinite loop. My guess is that *primlst* within **sieve-iter** is causing issues.

```
(define (sieve n) ;; returns the n:th prime (n>0) 
  (let [(primlst '(2))
        (cand 3)]
    (define (sieve-iter i lst)
      (cond ((null? lst) (and (cons i primlst) (sieve-iter (+ i 2) primlst))) ;;prime
            ((= (length primlst) n) (car primlst)) ;;end
            ((= (modulo i (car lst)) 0) (sieve-iter (+ i 2) primlst)) ;;non-prime
            (#t (sieve-iter n (cdr lst))))) ;;unclear if prime
  (sieve-iter cand primlst)))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trying to do too much in one function, let `prime-iter` just worry about the iteration to build up the list of primes. Make another internal function to recurse down the existing primes to test the new candidate.

```
(define (sieve n) ;; returns the n:th prime (n>0) 
  (define (sieve-iter i lst remaining)
    (cond ;((null? lst) (and (cons i primlst) (sieve-iter (+ i 2) primlst))) ;;should never be null, we are building the list up
            ((<= remaining 0) (car lst)) ;;checking length every time gets expensive added a variable to the function
            ((sieve-prime? i lst) ;;if prime add to lst and recurse on next i
             (sieve-iter (+ i 2) (cons i lst) (- remaining 1)))
            (else 
             (sieve-iter (+ i 2) lst remaining)))) ; else try next
  (define (sieve-prime? i lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) #t)
          ((= 0 (modulo i (car lst))) #f)
          (else (sieve-prime? i (cdr lst))))) 

    (let ((primlst '(2)) ;;you generally don't modify these, 
          (cand 3)) ;mostly they just bind values to name for convenience or keep from having to re-calculate the same thing more than once      
     (sieve-iter cand primlst (- n 1))))
```

You could have used set! to modify primlist where it was before, but the procedure is no longer obviously a pure function.

There is another low-handing optimization possible here, when calling sieve-prime? filter the lst argument to remove values larger than the square root of i.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't refer to `primlist` at all within the `sieve-iter` function. Instead, you should refer to `lst`.

Second of all, you appear to be mistaken on the effect of this expression:

```
(and (cons i primlst) (sieve-iter (+ i 2) primlst))
```

You seem to be interpreting that as meaning "Add `i` to the `primlist` and then start the next iteration."

`(cons i primlist)` changes nothing. Instead, it creates a new list consisting of `primlist` with `i` in front of it and then evaluates to that value. The original `primlist` (which should have been `lst` anyway) is left untouched.

Also, `and` is for Boolean logic, not for stringing commands together. It evaluates each of its subexpressions separately until it finds one that evaluates to `#f` and then it stops.

You should replace that whole expression with this:

```
(sieve-iter (+ i 2) (cons i lst))
```

...which passes the new list created by `cons` to the next run of `sieve-iter`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I don't see how this would achieve the intended effect. Once you've found one prime-number you call the procedure again but only with the latest prime neglecting the other primes. (Since *lst* in **sieve-iter** for when a number is prime will just be the empty list)

That's why I wanted work with a variable outside of the function which has the entire list and to which i can add elements in the iterations.